# Profile page tag scores doesn't work for me

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page

On [my page](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/576/vmatm) I have 6 tags on the bottom, and I have score on each of them, but I see only zeroes on my page. Title of each tag score working fine - it displays correct score on each tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your tag scores are only for **answers**, not questions.  These scores are a rough measure of how much you know about the subject, or rather, how much you've helped other people in those areas.  Feel free to answer some questions! :)